# How to get the content:encoded tag in android from rss feed

Tags: android, rss

I am trying to parse an rss feed: http://feeds.feedburner.com/Talk_Android

I've used an online tutorial and modified it.

I have successfully retrieved the title and pubDate. I also tried retrieving the description tag and it has worked .. However I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve the content:encoded tag.I want to retrieve both the title and the content:encoded Onclick of an item in the listview..The title comes out fine.. Upon Debugging the content is null which is obviously because I have used the string 'content' in my code which isn't present anywhere in the rss feed... I have gone through all the similar posts on this and still can't seem to get a clear picture of what I'm supposed to do .. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated..

here is the code for `NewsBean.java`

```
package com.samir;

public class NewsBean {

    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String pubDate;
    private String link;
    private String content;


    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getPubDate() {
        return pubDate;
    }

    public void setPubDate(String pubDate) {
        this.pubDate = pubDate;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content + " got null here ";
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }


}
```

Here is the code for `NewsMainActivity.java`

```
package com.samir;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NewsMainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {


    ListView listview;
    List<NewsBean> arrayList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        initComponents();

        if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
            new MyRssReadTask()
                    .execute("http://feeds.feedburner.com/Talk_Android");

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Network Connection!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

    }


    private void initComponents() {
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    class MyRssReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        ProgressDialog waitingDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            waitingDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewsMainActivity.this);
            waitingDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            waitingDialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

            arrayList = new NewsParser().getData(urls[0]);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            waitingDialog.dismiss();
            setDataToListView();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

    protected void setDataToListView() {
        if (null != arrayList && arrayList.size() != 0) {
            NewsRowAdapter objNewsRowAdapter = new NewsRowAdapter(
                    NewsMainActivity.this, R.layout.row, arrayList);

            listview.setAdapter(objNewsRowAdapter);
        } else {
            showToast("Error in geting Data From WebService!");
        }

    }

    void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(NewsMainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // do description showing work here 
        final NewsBean objBean = (NewsBean) arrayList.get(position);

        Intent intent = new Intent(NewsMainActivity.this,
                NewsDetail.class);
        intent.putExtra("title", objBean.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra("description", objBean.getDescription());
        intent.putExtra("content", objBean.getContent());

//      String encodedurl = null;
//      try {
//          encodedurl = URLEncoder.encode(objBean.getDescription(),"UTF-8");
//      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
//          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }
//      intent.putExtra("content",encodedurl );
//       

        startActivity(intent);



    }



} //NewsMain ends
```

Here is the code for `NewsDetail.java`

```
package com.samir;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NewsDetail extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail);

        Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();

        String title = b.getString("title");
        String desc = b.getString("description");
        String cont = b.getString("content");

//      String content = getIntent().getStringExtra("content");


        TextView tvtitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvtitle);
        TextView tvdesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdesc);//USED FOR CONTENT RIGHT NOW


        tvtitle.setText(title);
        tvdesc.setText(cont);
//      tvdesc.setText(content);
        //tvdate.setText(Utils.getDateFormate(date));

        setTitle(title);
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: See the code snippet here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579701/parse-rss-feed-for-android/24587871#24587871

Comment: is there any other way to do this except for the library that this code is using  ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library. It should work perfectly fine for you. 
https://github.com/Pkmmte/PkRSS

This RSS library is very easy to use and supports many different types of feeds. By default, it works with RSS 2.0 (which is what your feed uses) so it should be even easier.

To load and parse your feed in the background, the code would look like this:
PkRSS.with(this).load(url).async();

You may then retrieve the result in various different ways such as via a callback or simply:
List articleList = PkRSS.with(this).get(url);

Visit the GitHub page for more details. I built a tech news app using this library and it works wonders. :D