# I don't know how to parse rss blogger

Tags: android, rss, blogger, rss-reader

I have a problem with an `rss reader`
i use this code:
http://techiedreams.com/android-simple-rss-reader/

And it works with other websites but not with mi blogger blog, i try this feed url but in the app te activity stays with a white background and do not show anithing, in the log console i can't see anything strange.

```
minecraft-schematics.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=atom

minecraft-schematics.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss
```

I also try it with my wordpress blog (is the same) but it only works with `rdf format` and do not show any picture.

How can fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should try Blogger Atom XML (**http://minecraft-schematics.blogspot.com/atom.xml?redirect=false&start-index=1&max-results=500**) also...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library:
https://github.com/Pkmmte/PkRSS

It works with most RSS2 and Atom feeds but allows you to plug in your own parser if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try my AndroidWithoutStupid library. I tested it with the links you have given and it works fine.
https://github.com/vsubhash/AndroidWithoutStupid

Example is here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24587871/2014914

Update:

```
MvGeneral.startSyncDownload("http://www.example.com/rss.xml", "/mnt/sdcard/rss.xml");
MvNewsFeed oFeed = new MvNewsFeed("/mnt/sdcard/rss.xml");
for (int i = 0; i < oFeed.moMessages.size(); i++) {
  Log.d("YOUR_TAG", oFeed.moMessages.get(i).msMessageTitle);
  Log.d("YOUR_TAG", oFeed.moMessages.get(i).msMessageContent);
  Log.d("YOUR_TAG", oFeed.moMessages.get(i).msMessageLink);
}
```

Comment: please consider adding code rather than just posting links to a solution