# Parse content from a Wordpress blog

Tags: java, android, wordpress, rss

I have a blog built with Wordpress.org and I would like to create its Android app using AS. The problem is that I don't know what method use to get the posts from the blog. I've heard of parsing its RSS feed, using XML-RPC or even through a JSON API. It is just for reading the blog, not for writing posts, so it would be better if I don't need to create a WP user. Once parsed, which is the best way to show the post content? WebView? TextView? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For parsing RSS feed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25574570/2014914

You can set the value of a TextView with setTag method and links will appear like in a HTML page. It is much more accessible from Java. However, it is very deficient if you need to use images or more richer content. For this reason, use WebView to display your feed content. However, webview contents are not accessible from Java.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library to easily achieve that via RSS:
https://github.com/Pkmmte/PkRSS

It works natively with WordPress blogs but you can customize it however you want. As for displaying the actual article content, use a WebView for that and inject a CSS stylesheet if you wish to style the content.

There's a full example in the link.