# XML Parsing For News Application

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I have create news application rss feed on xml parsing for collage project
this is xml http://goo.gl/X8tIr1 so any one guide me for build that application or give code to help for collage project

Can Anyone give me the whole code

Comment: Try this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: See this answer for the question "Parse RSS feed for Android"
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24587871/4769696

Answer (score 1):

Go through [Creating-a-simple-rss-application-in-android](https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/creating-a-simple-rss-application-in-android/). This should get you started.

Comment: But hindi font not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving you how to XML PArsing works in `doInBackground`. Try like this :

```
        DOMParser dParser = new DOMParser();
        String abc = dParser.getXmlFromUrl(params[0]);
        Document doc = dParser.getDocElement(abc);
        NodeList n1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("channel");

        for (int i = 0; i < n1.getLength(); i++) {
            Element e = (Element) n1.item(i);
            NodeList nl1 = e.getElementsByTagName("item");

            for (int j = 0; j < nl1.getLength(); j++) {
                Element e1 = (Element) nl1.item(j);
                NodeList ntitle = e1.getElementsByTagName(TITLE);
                NodeList ndate = e1.getElementsByTagName(PUBDATE);
                NodeList ndesc = e1.getElementsByTagName(DESCRIPTION);

                for (int k = 0; k < n1.getLength(); k++) {
                    Element e2 = (Element) ntitle.item(k);
                    Element e3 = (Element) ndate.item(k);
                    Element e4 = (Element) ndesc.item(k);

                    Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
                    pojo.setTitle(getCharacterDataFromElement(e2));
                    pojo.setPubdate(getCharacterDataFromElement(e3));
                    pojo.setDescription(getCharacterDataFromElement(e4));
                    itemList.add(pojo);
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
```

Comment: Go to my profile and send me a blank email at my email address.